# One confusion on expectation

Tags: probability, probability-theory

In order to ensure that $E[\frac{X}{Y}]$ represents a valid expectation, it is necessary that the inverse moment $E[|\frac{1}{Y}|]$ be finite when $E[X]=0$. Here $X$ and $Y$ are independent. I don't understand why modulus is present here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because $E(Z)$ exists if and only if $E(|Z|)$ is finite. The only case when $E(XY)$ exists but $E(|Y|)$ is infinite is when $E(|X|)=0$, that is, when $P(X=0)=1$ (and then $E(XY)=0$, naturally).

Comment: I don't understand the necessary condition in the statement of the first line. We just need one of positive /negative part to be finite.

Comment: The commonest definition of integrability states that E(Z) is (finite and) defined if and only if E(|Z|) is finite.